# splitting and concatenating dataframes in Python pandas for plotting with rpy2

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, rpy2

I have a question about pandas dataframes in Python: I have a large dataframe `df` that I split into two subsets, `df1` and `df2`.  `df1` and `df2` together do not make up all of `df`, they are just two mutually exclusive subsets of it. I want to plot this in ggplot with rpy2 and display the variables in the plot based on whether they come from `df1` or `df2`. ggplot2 requires a melted dataframe so I have to create a new dataframe that has a column saying whether each entry was from `df1` or `df2`, so that this column can be passed to ggplot. I tried doing it like this:

```
# add labels to df1, df2
df1["label"] = len(df1.index) * ["df1"]
df2["label"] = len(df2.index) * ["df2"]
# combine the dfs together
melted_df = pandas.concat([df1, df2])
```

Now it can be plotted as in:

```
# plot parameters from melted_df and colour them by df1 or df2
ggplot2.ggplot(melted_df) + ggplot2.ggplot(aes_string(..., colour="label"))
```

My question is whether there's an easier, short hand way of doing this. ggplot requires constant melting/unmelting dfs and it seems cumbersome to always manually add the melted form to distinct subsets of df. Thanks.

Comment: One shortcut would be to replace `df1["label"] = len(df1.index) * ["df1"]` with `df1["label"] = "df1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you can simplify by using:

```
df1['label'] = 'df1'
```

(rather than `df1["label"] = len(df1.index) * ["df1"]`.)

If you find yourself doing this a lot, why not create your own function? (something like this):

```
plot_dfs(dfs):
    for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
        df['label'] =  'df%s' % i+1 # note: this *changes* df
    melted_df = pd.concat(dfs)

    # plot parameters from melted_df and colour them by df1 or df2
    ggplot2.ggplot(melted_df) + ggplot2.ggplot(aes_string(..., colour="label"))

    return # the melted_df or ggplot ?
```

Comment: Since the function is called `plot_dfs`, return the `ggplot` object, I'd say.