# melting uniquely indexed pandas dataframes for use with ggplot/rpy2

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ggplot2, rpy2

This question is related to ([splitting and concatenating dataframes in Python pandas for plotting with rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053834/splitting-and-concatenating-dataframes-in-python-pandas-for-plotting-with-rpy2)). I'm working with pandas dataframes and am doing various melting/unmelting/concatenation operations on them so that I can plot them with ggplot2 using rpy2. I'm a bit confused on how to do these operations on dataframes that have a unique index. Assume the dataframe `df` has a unique column,  `runner_id` which records the time and speed of each runner completed one of two races, races `A` and `B`. Each runner is unique and so the DataFrame can have this shape for two runners `bob` and `mary`:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([{"runner_id": "bob", "time_A": 30,
                        "time_B": 25, "speed_A": 5, "speed_B": 10},
                       {"runner_id": "mary", "time_A": 29,
                        "time_B": 19, "speed_A": 8, "speed_B": 12}])
```

`df` looks like this:

```
  runner_id  speed_A  speed_B  time_A  time_B
0       bob        5       10      30      25
1      mary        8       12      29      19
```

Since the runners are unique, it's very convenient to index the dataframe `runner_id`. It also safeguards from adding duplicates entries by accident, since we know all the information for each runner should be kept in the runner's row, and we can't have multiple rows per runner:

```
df = df.set_index("runner_id")
```

The problem is that ggplot needs to use the information in the column names `time_A, time_B, speed_A, speed_B`, if we want to plot the time or speed differences between the two races. Then the `df` would need to look like this:

```
runner_id  race  time  speed 
bob        A     ...   ...
mary       A     
bob        B
mary       B
```

So that we can do:

```
ggplot2.ggplot(df) + \
ggplot2.geom_point(aes_string(x="time", y="speed", colour="race")) ...
```

Though this violates the uniqueness of `runner_id` entries, since the runners will need to be duplicated. How does one deal with this in general? Is there a good form to keep `df` in that allows unique indexing but also convenient melt-ed representation for ggplot? I find it very difficult/confusing to go back and forth between these two. The first representation of having different time/speed columns per race, indexed by runner, is very intuitive, while the melted representation for ggplot is confusing and seems wasteful.

Any thoughts on converting back and forth between these two or general rules about how to keep the dataframe will be helpful. Is the answer not to index (not call `set_index`) when using ggplot?  Is there a preferred format for dataframes of this sort?

One potential solution is to always index/unindex the df when unmelting/melting, like:

```
melted_df = pandas.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars="runner_id")
```

but that seems error-prone. For example, if I want to calculate the mean of each runner's speed and time for the `A` race, I could try to put out the `A` entries:

```
# This is already complicated
a_entries = melted_df[map(lambda x: x.endswith("_A"), melted_df["variable"])]
```

I know have the redundant/melted representation, so it's hard to do operations that don't double count runners, since each runner appears twice now:

```
  runner_id variable  value
0       bob  speed_A      5
1      mary  speed_A      8
4       bob   time_A     30
5      mary   time_A     29
```

Answer (score 1):

Melting and casting data frames is a common operation in R. Hadley's package `reshape` (and `reshape2` where the original `melt()` is found are popular for a reason).

With ggplot2, you can also add data to a plot in layers. With your example:

```
import rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri
rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri.activate()

p = ggplot2.ggplot(rpy2.robjects.conversion.py2ri(df)) + \
    ggplot2.geom_point(ggplot2.aes_string(x="time_A",y="speed_A"),colour="#ff0000") + \
    ggplot2.geom_point(ggplot2.aes_string(x="time_B",y="speed_B"),colour="#0000ff") + \
    ggplot2.scale_x_continuous("time") + \
    ggplot2.scale_y_continuous("speed")
p.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and belated answer to a long question: it seem that you could use some help understanding long format data frames.  Each value is unique, because there is only one 'runner' with the given name per race.  It can melt your brain at first, but is extremely powerful and essential for taking advantage of the capabilities of ggplot2.  Hadley Wickham explains this quite well in a few articles, for example: http://had.co.nz/reshape/paper-dsc2005.pdf‎